# How to add 'current' class to navigation menu <li> using javascript.in a single page website?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried with codes like below, and it's removing current class but not adding new class to children

Navigation  between sections should happen and also change the link status to active class using 'current'

```js
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
  document.querySelector('.current').classList.remove('current');
  document.querySelector('[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').classList.add('current');
});
```

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse clearfix">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do and what the end results would be ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Very clear. The hash of the page determines the LI that has 'current' class

Comment: @mplungjan alright go for the answer.

Comment: You need to escape the hash

Comment: or `document.querySelector('[href$="' + window.location.hash.slice(1) + '"]')`

Comment: Its not working

Comment: You ALSO need to access the LI: `if (location.hash) {
        document.querySelector('[href$=' + window.location.hash.slice(1) + ']').closest("li").classList.add('current');
      }`

Comment: Something like this https://plungjan.name/SO/hashchange/index.html#portfolio